# Best practice for sliding in html

Tags: jquery

Using JQuery, what is the best way to slide in 3 different pieces of html content? There would also need to be a way to go "back" or show the other pieces of content that have been hidden if the user so desired.

Comment: Besided the fact that 'the best' is subjective this question is also way to broad and sounds more like a: `canihaztehcodez` question. Do you have a specific question?

Comment: Nah, to me it sounds like a "I know what I want but don't know what it's called" question.

Comment: It's not about winnning @Muzz :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you want a "carousel". You can use a `UL` with the `overflow` property set to `hidden`; each slide would go into a `LI`, and you can "slide" them by animating the `margin-left` property.

If you're too lazy to implement that, you can steal or check out the code of one of the zillions of freely available carousel implementations out there, just ask google.

Comment: This one is quite light-weight: http://code.google.com/p/simple-carousel/

Comment: Karim, that looks almost exactly like what I;m after, thank you. Do you know if I can put the button controls inside the actual window instead of having them outside?

Comment: You would probably have to use absolute positioning to overlay them yourself - I don't think that's something you can just "configure in", but it should be too difficult to achieve; set the position of the container to `relative`, place the button overlays inside the container and position them absolutely.